# span que reciba una respuesta con ${}

Tags: javascript, java, html

disculpen, una pregunta nadamás breve, intenté llamar un var de javascript o un string de java con un span

```
<span>${nombre}</span>
```

Pero la realidad es que se me fue el avión de como mandarlo a llamar y pues he tratado y no funciona nada, aparece en blanco, vacío y no, no funciona.
No sé si tenga que ver con un response o un out println, pero el chiste que recuerdo que si lo hice con javascript y esos métodos ya son de java, no funcionaría en javascript, y no recuerdo como en ninguna de las dos lenguas.
Si tienen la solución se los agradecería mucho que la compartieran, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hola tu pregunta es un tanto confusa, pero para imprimir un texto en una etiqueta HTML desde JS utilizas los backtics `` y un innerHTML en el elemento donde quieres mostrar la etiqueta.

```
let name = "texto a imprimir"
document.getElementById('algo').innerHTML = `<span>${name}</span>`
```

O simplemente asi para almacenarla en una variable

```
let nombreEtiqueta = `<span>${name}</span>`
```

Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: Será? Mm, voy a ver a ver si es cierto